# Validating type formats - can't find a way to validate an integer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I'm setting up a REST API using Web API 2, that connect to a EF Code first Database. I'm trying to validate that information is coming back as the correct format but can't find a way to validate this.

I'm trying to validate "CreditCardNumberLastFour" to be no more then 4 characters.

Validate PhoneNumber to match a Regex of a phone number and validate EmailAddress to match a Regex of an email address

I've tried reading plenty of Microsoft Docs around Web API and EF Code first DB and none of them talk about how this should be done.

So I've been googling my issue and seems to be a bit of an edge case and not covered.

```
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CreditCardNumberLastFour { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool UserInSession { get; set; }
        public Card Card { get; set; }
    }
```

//What I am trying to implement

```
    public class LastFour
    {
       //if User.CreditCardNumberLastFour.Length != 4
       //{
       //   
       //}
    }
```

//POST FROM API /, possibly thinking the check could go here? But unsure where that would take place.

```
    //POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]User value)
    {

        using (var db = new MembershipContext())
        {
            value = new User();
            db.Users.Add(value);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

For CreditCardNumberLastFour, I expect anything more or less than 4 characters to be rejected and everything that is 4 characters to be accepted.

Comment: `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` + `ModelState.IsValid`

Comment: Really, you are looking for a Regex for four decimal digits?  How about `\d{4}` (or, as you say somewhere else in your post "no more then 4 characters", then you'd need `\d{1,4}`.  Or, if you are looking for a non-Regex solution, consider combining `int.TryParse` with a comparison making sure that the result is between 1000 and 9999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: simply check the length of the string value

```
//POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]User value)
{
    // ensure only 4 characters in the string
    if (value.CreditCardNumberLastFour.Length != 4)
    {
        return;
    }
    using (var db = new MembershipContext())
    {
        value = new User();
        db.Users.Add(value);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to be more strict, ensure the values are all numbers

```
//POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]User value)
{
    // check for numbers only
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(value.CreditCardNumberLastFour, @"^\d+$")
    {
        return;
    }
    // ensure length is 4
    if (value.CreditCardNumberLastFour.Length != 4)
    {
        return;
    }
    using (var db = new MembershipContext())
    {
        value = new User();
        db.Users.Add(value);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Option 2: A validator on the class

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CreditCardNumberLastFour { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool UserInSession { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}

interface IValidator<T> {
    bool Validate(T t);
}

class UserValidator : IValidator<User> {
    public bool Validate(User u) {
        // check for numbers only
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(value.CreditCardNumberLastFour, @"^\d+$")
        {
            return false;
        }
        // ensure length is 4
        if (value.CreditCardNumberLastFour.Length != 4)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // add more checks here if needed ....
    }
}
```

Then, in your code, you're able to do the following

```
//POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]User value)
{
    var validator = new UserValidator();
    if (!validator.Validate(value)){
    {
        return;
    }
    using (var db = new MembershipContext())
    {
        value = new User();
        db.Users.Add(value);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Super Helpful! I'm now trying to get Validation for other values, will I need to call other Validate Methods?

Comment: @GenericDeveloper yes, you will need to declare more methods in the interface, and implement them in the class that extends it. Then, when using that validator class in the controller, you can use the new method you just implemented to validate whatever property you need

Answer (score 1):

You can explore ModelState Validation. Your code can be modified as -

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string CreditCardNumberLastFour { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool UserInSession { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

and Action -

```
public void Post([FromBody]User value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {

    }
}
```

You can explore more - [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)